# How to iterate over json data if there is anr array inside an array in the JSON output

Tags: json, angular

I have to iterate over the templte by adding the index like
{{single.amazon_data[i].Category}}

here is api :https://test.pickcel.com/api/v1/getAmazonDeals.  I have to explicitly provide the index of the array how to automate it?

```
  </component.ts>
  /*this list component calls api to fetch deals from amazon*/
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  /*importing services*/
  import { DealsService } from '../deals.service'


  @Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
  })

 export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
 public deals;

 constructor(public dealsHttpService : DealsService) {
 console.log('List component constructor is called');
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 console.log('List component onInit called');
  /*subscribing to observables*/
  this.dealsHttpService.getAmazonDeals().subscribe(
   data=>{
     console.log('logging data');
     this.deals = data["data"];
     console.log(this.deals)
   },
    /*handle error if not subscribed*/
     error => {
    console.log("some error occured");
    console.log(error.errorMessage);
  }
  )
   }



   }
    />


    </html template

      <td>{{single.amazon_data[0].Category}}</td>
      <td>{{single.amazon_data[0].Title}}</td>
      <td>{{single.amazon_data[0].Details}}</td>
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngFor="let item of deals.amazon_data"`

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let item of deals">
      <tr *ngFor="let item1 of item.amazon_data">
         <td>{{item1.Category}}</td>
   ...
</ng-container>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: ListComponent.html:18 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'amazon_data' of undefined

Comment: deals?.amazon_data

Comment: @vaibhavnaik Which data you want from `amazon_data` array?

Comment: what are you getting in this.deals? can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Can you please add your JSON formatted data for reference .

Comment: I want to fetch the category, Title,ASIN,Deatils inside a html table

Comment: I am hoping that you are storing your ```data``` Object to ```deals``` . then there is minor typing mistake is possible here.

Comment: <div>
<ng-container *ngFor = "let item of deals">
      <tr *ngFor="let item1 of item.amazon_data">
         <td>{{item1.Category}}</td>
   ...
</ng-container>
   </div>

Comment: @Zinal Thakkar your answer is correct but the details has an array how to use it

Comment: @vaibhavnaik same way *ngFor="let item2 of item1.details"